# Stop showing plots in spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I have scripts that make lots of plots. I save them directly with `plt.savefig()` rather than `plt.show()` so I don't have to close all the windows. In spyder, they all show up in the console if I use inline (meaning I have to scroll way back to see other output), and they all show up in separate windows if I use automatic. I want them to not show up at all, because I'm not calling `plt.show()` ever. How can I do that?

nb: Both the suggested answers work! Thanks! I selected plt.ioff() as the correct answer since I can choose to do this for some scripts and not others.

Comment: Strange, the plt.ioff() helped me only at first: now a day later, using the exactly same script, I do not get the png saved. The other answer does not help either in this situation. Not saying that the answers here are wrong. Yet, there seems to be a different problem in addition. I use Spyder 4.1.4 on Windows 10 64bit. The same script is running fine in PyCharm. Now open issue at https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13498.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (assuming imported pyplot as plt), at the start of the code somewhere:

```
plt.ioff()
```

Comment: `plt.ion()` gets it on again

Comment: This works with Seaborn. Deactivating Graphics support for MatPlotLib and `plt.close()` do not work with Seaborn.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want to turn spyder support for matplotlib off completely,

```
Preferences | IPython Consonle | Graphics | Support for Graphics
```

and untick `Activate`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with this issue, I figured that adding a **plt.close()** after plt.savefig() will do the work. (I'm using Spyder 5.1.5 with Python 3.8.12)